# Android mobile Browser jQuery keydown issue

Tags: jquery, android, browser, mobile, keydown

I want a textarea to respond to keydown.
I tried the following

```
<textarea id="text"></textarea>

$('#text').keydown(function() {
  alert('keydown');
});
```

This works fine on the Desktop but it's not working with the Android 2.3 Mobile Browser.
I tried the Dolphine Browser and there everything worked just fine.

I tried the jquery ui autocomplete component and it worked with the Android Mobile Browser.
I looked at the source code of the autocomplete component, but couldn't find out, why it worked and the simple keydown in my example didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:
This was some strange caching behavior by the android mobile browser.
Although the css changes were updated the javascript  wasn't. After I cleared all cached data in the mobile browser, everything worked just fine.